# testing angular controller functions with karma not on scope

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a controller that I am testing with Karma. I want to take some functions off of the scope but still independently test them. I have tried initializing them in the controller as simply

`function test() = {...}`

and that gives me this error in my test:

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: test`

If I try to do it like this

`this.test = function() {...}`

I get

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.test')`.

I can access scope functions just fine from the same test. Please help! New to angular

Comment: did you include a file with the function into karma conf `files` array?

Comment: Yes it is defined inside the controller function, and I am including the controller correctly. That is why I can access the controller's scope functions.

Comment: ohh, if you have that func inside controller then no, it is not possible to test it, it should be placed in the controller scope only